# Lebesgue measure of a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, triangles, area

"Proof that the Lebesgue measure of a triangle is the euclidean area."

Well, I know firstly that a triangle is measurable with finite measure, because is closed and bounded, and that the Lebesgue measure is invariant by translations. But I don't know how to prove it basing on what I've just said.

Can someone give me a hand on this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take some time to add context and explain where you're getting stuck. Imposing a deadline without showing your efforts so far doesn't come across well.

Comment: Now I think it's better formulated.

Comment: Thank you, that's much better.

Comment: So could you give me a hand on this please? I've been trying it for long time but there's something at the end of the demonstration that fails me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: I presume you know the measure of a rectangle is its area.  Two congruent triangles form a parallelogram, and a parallelogram can be dissected and the pieces
rearranged to form a rectangle.

EDIT: Another way to do it (assuming you know the measure of a square is its area): bound above and below the number of nonoverlapping squares of side $\epsilon$ that can fit inside the triangle.

Comment: The thing is I should prove it using Lebesgue measure properties. I mean, I know a triangle is measurable with finite measure, because is closed and bounded, and that the Lebesgue measure is invariant by translations. But I don't know how to prove finally that the Lebesgue measure of the triangle is its area. I don't know if I'm explaining well.

Answer (score 0):

I won't work out the full details, but I think the idea is this: the measure of the unit square $S$ with the canonical basis as sides in the plane has Lebesgue measure $\mu(S)=1$ (this should be obvious from the definition of $\mu$). Now consider the linear transformation $\phi$ that takes the canonical basis to two adjacent sides of the triangle $T$ (translate $T$ if needed). Then $\phi(S)$ is a parallelogram of area twice that of $T$, so $2\mu(T)=\mu(\phi(S))=|det\,\phi|\mu(S)=|det\,\phi|$ so it reduces to a linear algebra problem (I'm assuming you have seen why the det comes into play there, otherwise take a look at Folland theorem 2.44 for example)